# Detect when a key is pressed or not pressed using Corutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to C# and I'm trying to write my script for enemy AI. What I want is if the "S" key is pressed the enemy goes away (Fades out then fades back in using coroutine). If no key is pressed for a certain amount of time the game resets. Instead the enemy Debug.Log reset comes up at the start (which makes sense because it is in my start function. However, if I put it under update it updates every frame. Should I use FixedUpdate instead? I need a clear example of how this should go.

```cs
public GameObject gameOverPanel;
public float TimeLimit = 10f;
private bool pressS;

private void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("S")) {
        pressS = true;
        //Kills Owl
    }
    //Test
    if (!Input.GetKeyDown("S")) { //If key is not pressed within certian time
        pressS = false;
        //Reset screen Appears
        StopCoroutine(Reset());
        StartCoroutine(Reset());
    }
}

private IEnumerator Reset() {
    Debug.Log("Reset Taking place")
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(TimeLimit);

    //GameOverScreen Appears
    gameOverPanel.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: You do not call Reset() anywhere in your Update. So how is it supposed to fade in again? An else twig of the If doing the fade out would be the natural case to put a fade in.

Comment: *"If no key is pressed for a certain amount of time the game resets"* What do you mean by reset? *"Fades out then fades back in using coroutine"* Should this fade-in/out be done once or repeatedly? When does it stop?

Answer (score 2):

What you're requesting is a State-Based Engine using Coroutines. For this particular case, there are four states:

1. Enemy Fades In.
2. Enemy Waits for Input from the Player.
3. Enemy Fades Out.
4. Enemy Wins. Game Restarts.

The code below is a revision of the code you posted. I refactored the `Start()` and `Update()` Monobehaviours to be solely focused on starting the State-Engine and monitoring inputs from the player respectively.

`Start()` is only needed to prepare the Enemy for future operations in the State-Engine, so I used that location to execute the `EnemyFadeIn()` coroutine.

Input flags are not reset until `Update()`, so its suggested that all Input Calls occur in the Update Loop. This is also why Input handling was removed from the `Start()` Monobehaviour. You can find more on this in the [Unity Article for Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html). However, all remaining functions shown in your code can run in coroutines smoothly.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public float waitTime = 10.0f;
    public float fadeTime = 3.0f;
    public float betweenFadesTime = 2.0f;

    // Flag to determine whether or not the player may respond.
    public bool canRespond = false;

    // Flag to determine if the player has responded within the wait time.
    public bool hasResponded = false;

    public GameObject enemy;

    void Start()
    { StartCoroutine(EnemyFadeIn(fadeTime, betweenFadesTime, waitTime)); }

    void Update() {
        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) && (canRespond))
        { hasResponded = true; }
    }

    IEnumerator EnemyFadeIn(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
        Debug.Log("An Enemy Is Fading In");
        // Simulating Fade In Time.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToFade);
        // Fade in
        // iTween.FadeTo(enemy, 1, 1);
        // Invoke("SetMaterialOpaque", 1f);
        Debug.Log("An Enemy Has Appeared");

        yield return ListenForInput(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait);
    }

    IEnumerator EnemyFadeOut(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
        Debug.Log("An Enemy Is Fading Away");
        // Simulating Fade Out Time.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToFade);
        // Fade out
        // SetMaterialTransparent();
        // iTween.FadeTo(enemy, 0, 1);
        Debug.Log("An Enemy Has Departed");
        // Simulating Time Between Fades.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeBetweenFades);

        yield return EnemyFadeIn(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait);
    }

    // Responsible for reacting to the 'S' key input.
    IEnumerator ListenForInput(float timeToFade, float timeBetweenFades, float timeToWait) {
        canRespond = true;
        Debug.Log("Press the 'S' Key to Destroy the Enemy!");
        float startTime = Time.time;

        // Check every 0.25 seconds to see if the S key was pressed.
        while (Time.time < (startTime + timeToWait)) {
            if (hasResponded) {
                Debug.Log("The 'S' Key was Pressed!");
                hasResponded = false;
                canRespond = false;
                yield return EnemyFadeOut(timeToFade, timeBetweenFades, timeToWait);
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        }

        Debug.Log("The 'S' Key was not Pressed!");
        canRespond = false;
        yield return ResetGame();
    }

    IEnumerator ResetGame() {
        Debug.Log("Game is Performing a Reset");
        //Simulating Game Reset Time.
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
        Debug.Log("Game has Restarted. End of Coroutine!");
    }
}
```

I created the `EnemyFadeOut()` and `ListenForInput()` methods to accompany the `EnemyFadeIn()` and `ResetGame()` methods. These are your four states. The behaviour flows as follows:

First, the `Start()` Monobehaviour starts the `EnemyFadeIn()` coroutine.

Next, the `EnemyFadeIn()` coroutine will pass control over to `ListenForInput()` upon fully phasing the enemy into the game world.

Next, the `ListenForInput()` coroutine will pass control over to either `EnemyFadeOut()` if the 'S' key was pressed within the given waitTime, or `ResetGame()` if the 'S' key was not pressed in time.

If control is passed to `EnemyFadeOut()`, the enemy will phase out of the world, and then control will pass to `EnemyFadeIn()` and the cycle will continue until the player fails to press the 'S' key.

If control is passed to `ResetGame()`, then the player has failed to press the 'S' key in time, and the game will perform all necessary functions to restart.

Console `Debug.Log()` and `yield return new WaitForSeconds()` are used for simulation purposes. Since iTween is not a native library on my end, some Fade In/Out code had to be commented out.

Comment: Happy to help. A word of constructive critique though. Comments are not recommended for compliments, as they do not add new information to the question at hand.

Instead, if you've found an answer helpful, a simple up-vote and marking the response as having answered your question is all that's needed. If you can, be sure to pay it forward by helping another. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment for details.

Comment: Quick Question I notice that the EnemyFadeIn and Enemy Fade out function use the same time. Is there any way I can delay the fade in so it doesnt appear right after I press S.

Comment: Remember that `yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToFade);` is only a placeholder for the actual fading transition. `WaitForSeconds()` should be replaced with your iTween code. Once the Fade Out is completed, you could implement a `WaitForSeconds(float timeBetweenFades)` where `timeBetweenFades` is an amount of time between Fade Out and Fade In. I updated my code to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are starting the Couroutine EnemyFadeIn() in the Start() function which means it gets called as soon as the object that the script has attached gets instantiated. Your ResetEnemy() method gets called as well unless you manage to press the S key right in the moment where the object gets instantiated which is very unlikely. So the EnemyFadeIn() method only gets called once. If you want ResetEnemy() to be called when no key has been pressed for a certain amount of time you will need to set a timestamp each time a key is pressed like that:

```
float lastTimePressedButton;

void Start() {
    lastTimePressedButton = Time.time;
}

void Update() {
    if(Input.GetKeyCode(KeyCode.S)) {
        lastTimePressedButton = Time.time;
    }
    if(Time.time >= lastTimePressedButton + 5f) {
         ResetEnemyOrWhatever();
         lastTimePressedButton = Time.time;
    }
}
```

[FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) should only be used when you want to deal with Rigidbodys is just a different loop then Update is.

Also GetKeyDown, GetKeyUp and GetKeyUp are considered bad practice and you should instead be using GetButtonDown,GetButtonUp and GetButton.

FYI when asking at Stackoverflow you should write what functions you call actually do. Itween is not part of the .Net Framework or Unity and I doubt many people know what this library(I suppose it is a library) does.

Comment: Thank you for the advice it's my first time on here. Also when I tried your suggestion the Debug.Log ("Reset Screen"); still spams over and over in update.

Comment: I currently can't test my code and I missed something after looking over it again. Could you try this again? It should call the method ResetEnemyOrWhatever() all 5 seconds when no key has been pressed. If you only want this to occur once then you will need to set a bool to true as soon as it happened once and compare if the bool is not true.

Comment: So I did a bool statement but I'm still confused about how to write this out in a clean format. Please help me rewrite this in a cleaner state.

Comment: When it is working as intended and you want cleaner code you should maybe read about [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and in general try to create meaningful methods to avoid double code, also when working with Unity you should follow the idea of [ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system) and avoid having multiple different features in the same script. Also you should never write values like the "5f" like I did. I only did so to make it easier to understand. Instead you should declare a variable like timeTillEnemyReset.

Comment: I ment to link to [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: And the coroutine?